# More than 2 client with OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

i have a question i install OpenVPN on my server and create the client config and my problem is only two client can be connected when i try to connect from third device the VPN cannot connect ive made a bad config? Or OpenVPN can only support two connections ? 
Thanks for any answer 
Im installing OpenVPN from that script
[angristan-OpenVPN-install](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install)

Comment: One OpenVPN server can support probably thousands of clients at a time.  Can you post your server configuration file here, with all the extra comments removed?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install  , works fine to me.And make sure your server has a physical or virtualized network, usually servers with guest networks tend not to work properly

Comment: I have information that this script NOT support ubuntu 16.04 ;/

Answer (score 0):

@xinthose config below

```
port 11122
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_AtrZgHsFgIwdNMkG.crt
key server_AtrZgHsFgIwdNMkG.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Like i said im using this script angristan-OpenVPN-install and that script generated this configuration only what i changed is port

I do not have more knowledge about openvpn, I am also asking for your understanding